# How can i get the key/name of the called tab in twig

Tags: twig, symfony

Is there any way to get the name of the tab in witch I'm actually in?

For example i have something like this:

{{ form.parent.vars.value }} - how can i get the string "Machine" without using {% for ... %} ?

```
#1930 ▼
    +vars: array:25 [▶]
    +parent: FormView {#1926 ▼
      +vars: array:24 [▼
        "value" => Machine {#1536 ▶}
        "attr" => []
        "form" => FormView {#1926}
        "id" => "tier_collection_forms_0"
        "name" => "0"
```

Hope my question is clear enough

Answer (score 2):

With the [keys filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/keys.html) ?

```
{{ (form.parent.vars.value|keys)[0] }}
```